# Javascript method to navigate to other url

Tags: javascript

Probably a stupid question, but is there a Javascript method to browse another url, from the existing window, not window.open() that would open another window

So something that edit the window.document.URL (possible) and refresh? not sure its possible client-side

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
window.location="http://www.dignaj.com";
```

You can also use navigate like this (*only works in some IE*)

```
window.navigate("http://www.dignaj.com");
```

Comment: window.navigate is a non-standard IE method unsupported by many other browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chrome).

Comment: does not work in chrome

Answer (score 13):

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Or:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

If you want to refresh you can use the method `reload`:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

For more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
window.location.replace('http://www.google.ch')
```